# What is stateless trigger in salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger

What is stateless trigger?
can anyone give me explanation with some code example and definition example ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you meant Logic-less triggers?

A StateLess trigger is simply a trigger code which does not perform any logic and does not execute any DML statements. 
It simply assigns the logic to a Trigger Handler Class. 
For Example 
Refer to this discussion : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093cKIAQ

It is a best practice to have only one trigger for each object and then create multiple trigger handlers to manage complex trigger logic. 
Refer the following link :-
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices

Comment: [Watch this SalesforceDeveloper Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeXyIv280nQ)

Comment: I am not sure about stateless trigger at all. so can't say anything